# Rewriting expected value for Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability

I don't understand the given solution for this problem:

"Having observed N=n, perform n Bernoulli trials with success probability $\theta$, getting X success. Prove that the estimator $X/N$ is unbiased for $\theta$ and has variance $\theta(1-\theta)E(1/N)$ "

Solution:

[image]
How did they get the first equal signs? That is, why does these 2 equality holds:

$E(\frac{X}{N}) = E(E(\frac{X}{N}|N))$

$Var(\frac{X}{N}) = Var(E(\frac{X}{N}|N)) + E(Var(\frac{X}{N}|N))$

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, $$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]]=\mathbb E[X]$$

always hold. This come from the fact that $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]$ is the unique $\mathcal G-$measurable r.v. such that for all $U$ bounded and $\mathcal G-$measurable, $$\mathbb E[XU]=\mathbb E[U\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal G]].$$